# HTTP Handler problem

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, httphandler

I've got an HTTP handler set up in the web.config file:

```
        <add verb="*" path="*_*.aspx" type="SeoHandler"/>
```

And have a file SeoHandler.ashx in the root of my web site that points to a SeoHandler.ashx.cs in the App_Code folder (the web site isn't a Web Application project).

When I run the site locally and type in a URL like "dork_test.aspx", the request is redirected to the handler where it then takes care of business.

But when the compiled site is running on my domain, "dork_test.aspx" will result in:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource
>   you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed,
>   had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please
>   review the following URL and make sure
>   that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /dork_test.aspx

Why would SeoHandler catch the "dork_test.aspx" request locally but not on the server?

Not sure if this matters, but when I hit the URL SeoHandler.ashx on my domain, the handler works like it's suppose to.

Is it possible that the web host has some IIS setting that ignores my entry in `<httpHandlers>`?

Answer (score 8):

Check in IIS on the server that the .NET handler is not set to verify the requested path physically exists:

- Go to Properties of the web site or virtual directory
- Home Directory tab
- Click "Configuration" in the lower section
- Find the extension for .ASPX and click edit, there is a checkbox that says "Verify that file exists".

If that checkbox is checked, .NET will not serve any requests that don't map to a physical file in the same location.

Comment: Damn, all the admins for my hosting company are gone until monday. Ugh. I'll direct them there when I can get a hold of them. Thanks Rex!

Comment: @Chris appreciate it, but you should probably wait to accept my answer after you've confirmed with your admins this is the problem :)

Comment: +1 It's late. My deployment's gone wrong. Unchecked "Verify file exists" - success! Im off to bed.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to get it to work on IIS 7.  Are you using a shared hosting provider that have something like URLScan installed?  Can you see if there are non-default settings at the server level?

Answer (score 1):

Rex M's got the right answer but I just tried something similar to handle .jpg and it failed.

The checkbox that says "Verify that file exists" is very important but still you have a issue with the Authorization for that folder.

I then tried to change the new web.config that I added for that folder and added

```
    <authorization>
                       <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
```

And it worked. So there is something going on with the Authorization process that doesn't let me handle the .jpg requests. And yes, I am authenticated in that app and It still fails if I try to request a .jpg.

Hope this solves to prove that your Handler works fine but that for that you need to had a major security issue...